# Why my script is returning last else right after loading the page?

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, onload

I don't know why code is executed right after loading the page. It should be executed after clicking the button (function onclick).  Script is returning "koszt paliwa:0zł." The browser isn't returing any errors (.........................................................................................)

```
 //javascript
            var rodzaj = document.getElementById("rodzajPaliwa").value;
            var ilosc = document.getElementById("litry").value;
            
            function pierwszyrodzaj(){
                ilosc *= 4
                document.getElementById("koncowacenapaliwa").innerHTML = "koszt paliwa:" + ilosc + "zł";
            }
            function drugirodzaj(){
                ilosc *= 3.5
                document.getElementById("koncowacenapaliwa").innerHTML = "koszt paliwa:" + ilosc + "zł";
            }
            function inny(){
                document.getElementById("koncowacenapaliwa").innerHTML = "koszt paliwa: 0zł";
            }
            
            function marcin (){
                if(rodzaj = 1){
                    pierwszyrodzaj();
                }else if(rodzaj = 2){
                    drugirodzaj();
                }else{
                    inny();
                }
                
            }
            
            document.getElementById("oblicz").onclick = marcin();
        
        //html
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="pl-PL">
        
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
            <title>STACJA PALIW</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="styl3.css">
        </head>
        
        <body>
        
            <div id="baner-lewy">
                <h1>Stacja paliw</h1>
            </div>
        
            <div id="baner-prawy">
                <a href="index.html">
                    <img src="home.png" alt="">
                </a>
                <a href="obliczenia.html">
                    <img src="znak.png" alt="">
                </a>
            </div>
        
            <main>
                <h3>Oblicz koszt paliwa</h3>
        
                <label for="rodzajPaliwa">Rodzaj paliwa (1-benzyna, 2-olej napędowy): </label><br>
                <input type="number" name="" id="rodzajPaliwa"><br><br>
                <label for="litry">Ile litrów: </label><br>
                <input type="number" id="litry"><br>
                <br>
                <button id="oblicz" >OBLICZ</button>
            </br>
                <span id="koncowacenapaliwa"></span>
          
                <script src="skrypt.js"></script>
            </main>
        
            <div id="blok-lewy">
                <a href="kwerendy.txt" download="kwerendy">Pobierz kwerendy</a>
            </div>
        
            <div id="blok-prawy">
                <img src="samochod.png" alt="samochód">
            </div>
            
        
        
        
            <footer id="">
                <p>&copy; Stronę wykonał: Jan Kupczyk 4TID</p>
            </footer>
        
        
          
        </body>
        
        </html>
```

[image: how it looks]

Comment: Single equals is only for assignment, not comparison.

Comment: That because you are calling function, change `document.getElementById("oblicz").onclick = marcin()` to this: `document.getElementById("oblicz").onclick = marcin` (Removed `()`)